# Finding the Previous and Next Date

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting the output I'm getting from this JavaScript function?

```
mod.getAdjacentDates = function (year, month, date) {
    var prevDate = new Date(year, month, date);
    var nextDate = new Date(year, month, date);

    prevDate.setDate(date - 1);
    nextDate.setDate(date + 1);

    var data = {
        prevDate: prevDate.getDate(),
        prevMonth: prevDate.getMonth() + 1,
        prevYear: prevDate.getFullYear(),
        nextDate: nextDate.getDate(),
        nextMonth: nextDate.getMonth() + 1,
        nextYear: nextDate.getFullYear()
    };

    alert(year + '-' + month + '-' + date + ' ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    return data;
};
```

The output I get from the alert is:

```
2013-12-17
{
   "prevDate":16,
   "prevMonth":1,
   "prevYear":2014,
   "nextDate":20,
   "nextMonth":6,
   "nextYear":2014
 }
```

I expected to get the following output:

```
2013-12-17
{
  "prevDate":16,
  "prevMonth":12,
  "prevYear":2013,
  "nextDate":18,
  "nextMonth":12,
  "nextYear":2013
}
```

Comment: date is string in arguments ?

Comment: That's not the output I get: http://jsfiddle.net/nFbBW/

Comment: @eicto might have a point here, I think my second date is trying to set the date to '171'.  Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try your code I get:

```
{
  "prevDate":16,
  "prevMonth":1,
  "prevYear":2014,
  "nextDate":18,
  "nextMonth":1,
  "nextYear":2014
}
```

You need to subtract one from the month when you create the dates also:

```
var prevDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
var nextDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
```

If you create a date with a month value of `12`, it will spill over into the year so that it becomes a date in january the next year.

Comment: Thanks, that's looking much better, the `prevDate` is bang-on now, but not the `nextDate`?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips: If you don't get a correct next date, then your actual code is different from what you posted. I get the correct date when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/s3D62/

Answer (score 1):

`#.getMonth()` is zero based, while the rest are 1 based.